# How can I make the Table View non-editable in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I dragged a Table View from the library, and linked the datasource and delegate, it worked. But when the Application is running, I can double click the row in the table, and actually put some words in it. I just want it to be non-editable. What should I do?

Comment: Are you using `UITextField`s to display text?

Comment: When you tap a certain area of the table view cell, does the keyboard pop-up?

Comment: Sorry, I am building a Mac app, not iOS...

Comment: LOL, it would probably help if you specify that in your question. Hmmm, I don't have experience with writing OS X apps, but it sounds like you are using text fields to display text. Otherwise, the text wouldn't be editable.

Comment: Wow, ignore what I just said about using text fields... I just looked at the documentation for NSTableView and it's quite different from UITableView (iOS). Sorry.

Comment: Alright, buddy, thanks for your comments though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the following delegate method that will return NO

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That's what I want. Thanks! Btw, I'm learning cocoa right now, how can solve this kind of problems by myself instead if asking questions here? Can you give me some advice when learn cocoa? Thanks!

Comment: These kind of basic functionalities are readily provided by Cocoa. Before using any Cocoa class, just spare 10 to 15 mins for reading the class documentation and related classes(like delegates, datasources, super class...etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can just uncheck the Editable button in table column attributes in xib file.
[image]